# Command Prompt to connect to a Redis cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I have a redis cluster. I can connect to the cluster with ec2, via ssh. 
In the ec2 instance, I have to prompt to my redis cluster node with this:

```
PROMPT> src/redis-cli -h mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

I tried this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-128 redis-stable]$ src/redis-cli -h red-aptitus-one.wqaipl.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379  
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-128 redis-stable]$
```

It gives me nothing, prompt didn't changed.

Also tried this:

```
PROMPT> src/redis-cli -h mycachecluster.eaogs8.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379

bash: PROMPT: Order not found
```

I've updated all packages and installed Development tools in my Amazon Linux instance, but it didn't help.

I am following the instructions in AWS docs (step 4):
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.Redis.html

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you have `redis-cli` installed? The 1st command you ran must have returned something: either that binary isn't present (looks like that command is for someone who's built Redis from the sources) or `redis-cli` would report an error. By "nothing", do you mean that the client just hung?

Comment: what happens when you enter `which redis-cli`? If you get a pathname like `/usr/bin/redis-cli`, then the command is installed. If you get no response, then redis-cli is not available and you'll need to install it.

Comment: `Which redis-cli` returns /usr/local/bin/redis-cli. When I enter redis-cli, it just comes back to the actual prompt. It doesn't hung, doesn't return an error.

Comment: @aimstone "actual prompt" == shell prompt?

Comment: This is what I have:

    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-128 redis-stable]$ src/redis-cli -h red-aptitus-one.wqaipl.0001.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379  
    [ec2-user@ip-172-31-26-128 redis-stable]$   

It doesn't return anything

Comment: @ItamarHaber, my last comment is not clear. I edited my question with the real prompt and command I want to execute. Thanks

Comment: So the cli just exits silently - that's weird. Maybe try rebuilding preceded with `make distclean`?

Comment: @ItamarHaber, thanks for your help, I rebuilded after `make distclean` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are copying the "PROMPT>" part, which you aren't supposed to type.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question. I tried without "prompt" and with, just in case. My tries were replacing with my node values, of course.